# activerecord find conditions for associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

so i havent found much documentation about using conditions on activerecord find methods for associated models, but i have found a variety of examples.  although none of them seem to be working for me.

```
user has_one avatar
avatar belongs_to user

Avatar.find(:all, :include => :user, :conditions => {:user => {:login => 'admin'}})
```

returns the ridiculously long error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user.login: SELECT "avatars"."id" AS t0_r0, "avatars"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "avatars"."featured" AS t0_r2, "avatars"."avatar_file_name" AS t0_r3, "avatars"."avatar_content_type" AS t0_r4, "avatars"."avatar_file_size" AS t0_r5, "avatars"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "avatars"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "users"."id" AS t1_r0, "users"."login" AS t1_r1, "users"."email" AS t1_r2, "users"."crypted_password" AS t1_r3, "users"."password_salt" AS t1_r4, "users"."persistence_token" AS t1_r5, "users"."perishable_token" AS t1_r6, "users"."login_count" AS t1_r7, "users"."failed_login_count" AS t1_r8, "users"."last_request_at" AS t1_r9, "users"."current_login_at" AS t1_r10, "users"."last_login_at" AS t1_r11, "users"."current_login_ip" AS t1_r12, "users"."last_login_ip" AS t1_r13, "users"."created_at" AS t1_r14, "users"."updated_at" AS t1_r15 FROM "avatars"  LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users".id = "avatars".user_id WHERE ("user"."login" = 'admin')
```

i have tried a variety of other patterns including

```
:conditions => "user.login == 'admin'"
```

but nothing is working.

this is with a rails 2.3.8 app, but rails3 is installed as well.  so i have activerecord 3.0.0 & 2.3.8 installed.  i thought this may be an issue, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Does user have a field called login?

Comment: remember to upvote useful answers and check the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
:user => {:login => 'admin'}
```

try

```
:users => {:login => 'admin'}
```

user**s**

Answer (score 1):

The standard Rails format for table names in the database itself is "all lower case, plural."

So you can debug your SQL error and see:

```
no such column: user.login
```

Since we know the table name is "users" the problem is that you're referencing table "user"

Fix depends on the version of Active Record. I prefer old school since it makes it more clear that the condition clause is SQL, not Ruby/Rails:

```
Avatar.find(:all, :include => :user,
  :conditions => "users.login = 'admin'")
```

Note: Rails 3 is different from the above...

Added:

Remember that if you're looking up a login supplied as a parameter from the user, you *must* properly escape the parameter. Rails makes this easy:

```
user_login = "admin"  # or, for example, params['user']
Avatar.find(:all, :include => :user,
  :conditions => ["users.login = ?", user_login])
```

Comment: geez louise... that worked. thanks larry(and gertas)! its great when solutions are so simple, but it really makes me feel thick!

Comment: login seems to be variable in brewster's original query, but your example may encourage SQL injection. Educate by example.

Comment: @Gertas: I read his example as looking for the unique login "admin". users.login is the table_name.field_name  But I agree with your point about using the safest examples since it isn't safe to make assumptions about SO. I've updated the example.